# UITextfield value successfully updated, but not shown in table

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

In my app rows are added to my `TableView` from a different view. When the user adds the rows the user is taken back to the `TableView`. The problem is that the text that was previously entered is no longer shown.

I am able to load it with an `NSMutableDictionary` but the user cannot see it. Any ideas on what I should do? what code I should add and where I should add it? Thanks a lot!

Here is code from a `tableview` method. I think the fix will go in here somewhere.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.wtf = [[UITextField alloc]init];

    NSUInteger count =0;
    for (NSMutableDictionary *search in dataForAllRows){ //this just helps me pull the right data out of an array of NSMutableDictionary's

        if ([search valueForKey:@"indexSection"] == [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(indexPath.section -1)]) {

            if ([search valueForKey:@"indexRow"] == [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]) {

                NSMutableDictionary *match = [dataForAllRows objectAtIndex:count];
                [cell.wtf setText:[match objectForKey:@"wtf"]]; 
                NSLog(@"%@",cell.wtf.text); // this outputs the correct value in the command line
            }
        }
        count++;
     }
   }
}
```

Here is the code for my CustomCell.m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize wtf, cellPath;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code

 } 

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
// Configure the view for the selected state
}
-(void)layoutSubviews{
wtf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 3, 65, self.contentView.bounds.size.height-6)];

self.wtf.delegate = self;

[wtf setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
[wtf setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[wtf setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
[wtf setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
wtf.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
wtf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;  //
[wtf setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];
[wtf setPlaceholder:@"enter"];

[self.contentView addSubview:wtf];
}
```

Comment: Two improvements would make your life much easier: (1) Is the cell defined in a storyboard/ib?  If not, do that, (2) a simple transformation of your datasource (dataForAllRows) would clarify the code and avoid a full search of the data every time a row scrolls into view.

Comment: @danh No my cell is not defined in story board/ib. I'll look up how to do that. Is that the root of my problem?  Sorry if some of my questions are basic. I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: Could you add `cell.wtf.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];` to your code to make sure that the textfield is being added to the cell correctly. And also share the code where you add the UITextfield to the cell.

Comment: In a way yes.  Not defining the cell in IB forces you to do it in code, which is much more error prone, and it does appear that your code omits a couple necessary steps.  See answer below.

Comment: @williamb when I added `cell.wtf.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];` to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` nothing happened. When I added that code in my CustomCell.m file it worked and the background color was green. I add the `UITextfield` to the cell in my CustomCell.m file. I'll add that code to my question soon. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: @njyulan I've updated my answer to include changes to the ExerciseCell class - I think the cause of the may have been overriding the `wtf` instance in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to load text into the `UITextField` in the `CustomCell` I added the following method

## CustomCell.m

```
-(void)viewMyCellData{
//here I can set text to my textfield
wtf.text = @"Desired Text"; //this will read in every wtf textfield in the table
//getting the right text from an array will be asked in another question that I will post
//in a comment to this answer
}
```

Next we call this using `[self viewMyCellData]`
at the end of our
`-(void)layoutSubviews` method which is also in `CustomCell.m`

Comment: [Posted Follow Up Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800977/save-and-get-uitableviewcell-data-when-new-sections-are-added-as-section-0)

Answer (score 1):

Consider defining the cell with identifier @"Cell" in IB as a prototype row of the table.  Then, use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` to retrieve the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  It's easier to understand what your cells will look like, and you can avoid some mistakes that are common when defining subviews in code.

Speaking of common mistakes, your code appears to present a couple: it doesn't frame the text field, nor does it add it as a subview of the cell.  Both would explain not seeing the text field.

@williamb's advice is correct and necessary: only build the cell's subview's if they are absent, but the building of the cell is incomplete...

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UITextField *wtf = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,200,42];
    [wtf setDelegate:self];
    [cell addSubview:wtf];
    cell.wtf = wtf;
}
```

As I mentioned in comment, a sectioned table ought to be supported by a 2D array.  The outer array is an array of sections.  Each section array is an array of dictionaries equal to the ones you're searching each time through this method, but pre-arranged so all that's done in cellForRowAtIndexPath is indexing into an array:

```
NSDictionary *d = self.myCorrectlyStructuredModel[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
cell.wtf.text = d[@"wtf"];
```

It's not a big challenge to build this from what you have.  Consider doing this right after you solve the text field problem.  I (or others) can give you some advice -- if you need any -- about how to build that structure.

Comment: Hi @Danh. Thanks for your answer. I definitely agree that a 2D array is a better way of going about saving the table data and I will work on that after I solve this problem. On a separate note, the problem with my UITextfield is not with there being a textfield. (I defined it in the customCell.m file that I just edited into my original question) The problem I'm encountering is that when I add new cells and go back to the `TableView` the `UITextfield` only shows the placeholder text that is assigned to it. It does not load the cell.wtf.text value.

Comment: Hello again. I have solved part of my problem and was wondering if you could share any advice with me. I have been able to load some of my data into my UITextField from my array of NSMutableDictionary's.. But it's not loading like I want it to. I initially chose to use a dictionary over a 2d array because every new section becomes section 0 in the table and a dictionary was the only solution is could think of. How can I use a 2d array when I add sections this way? Thanks!!

Comment: Consider this question to be about setting up the cell views. Hopefully it is solved and should be marked correct.  Please create a question about what kind of model is best for the type of table you want. Please describe the table and the data and leave me a link here.

Comment: Here is the link.  [New Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800977/save-and-get-uitableviewcell-data-when-new-sections-are-added-as-section-0)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are only setting the text value of your textfield if that cell does not exist and overriding your textfield instance to one that does not have a frame as @danh mentioned. What I believe you want to do is reuse the textfield once it is added to your cell's `contentview` and change what that textfield shows for each index path.

Try refactoring your cell code to be more like:

```
@implementation ExerciseCell

#pragma mark - Init

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
    reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style
                reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self)
    {
        wtf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 3, 65, 44)];

        wtf.delegate = self;

        [wtf setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
        [wtf setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
        [wtf setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
        [wtf setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        wtf.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        wtf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad; 
        [wtf setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];
        [wtf setPlaceholder:@"enter"];

        [self.contentView addSubview:wtf];        
    }

    return self;
}
```

and your tableview datasource class to be more like

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       [cell.wtf setDelegate:self];
   }

    NSUInteger count = 0;
    for (NSMutableDictionary *search in dataForAllRows){ //this just helps me pull the right data out of an array of NSMutableDictionary's

        if ([search valueForKey:@"indexSection"] == [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(indexPath.section -1)]) {

            if ([search valueForKey:@"indexRow"] == [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]) {

                NSMutableDictionary *match = [dataForAllRows objectAtIndex:count];
                [cell.wtf setText:[match objectForKey:@"wtf"]]; 
                NSLog(@"%@",cell.wtf.text); // this outputs the correct value in the command line
            }
        }
        count++;
     }
   }
}
```

Also do you mean to assign the the textField's delegate twice? Once in the cell and once in the tableview's datasource?

Comment: I tried your code and i'm still not seeing the text when the view is loaded. Would you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Are you changing the text color of your textfields anywhere else on your code or reset the text value? It's odd because with that NSLog you print out the cell.wtf.text and you say that it has the correct value

Comment: No, I do not change the color anywhere. I'm pretty sure I don't reset the text value. When the text is inputted it is put in an NSMutableDictionary which is then put in an array. then in the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' i pull it out of that array. I just don't know how to get it to be viewable. i tried `[self.tableview reloadData]` after I set the text and the bottom row disappears. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. I used the code in the ExerciseCell.m file. On the `return cell;` line  I received and error: Use of undeclared identifier 'cell'. I modified the code to `return self;` it ran but the rows were missing the wtf `UITextField`.

Comment: It could be that the height of the cell isn't being set at that moment - I've updated the code to hardcode the height value. Could you give that a try and let me if you have any issues,  could you also add a break point to make that that init method is being called.

Comment: I used your updated code and the UITextfield was still not added to the content view. I also added a NSLog in the init method. The method is called, but it seems like the method is called twice. I'm not sure why it's doing that. I did not intentionally mean to assign the textfield'd delegate twice. I removed the assignment in the tableview datasource. I really appreciate your continued help.

Comment: I figured out how to make my text appear(kind of). I created a `-(void)viewDidLoad` in my CustomCell.m. I then moved my enumeration from my `cellForRowAtIndex` to the `-(void)viewDidLoad`. I called `[self viewDidLoad]` at the end of my `(void)layoutSubviews`. When I add a new section the previous section loads the text that had been entered. but when I go on to add more sections the only section to have text in it is section 1.